# Site content expanding and contracting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple full screen site where the side bar is a constant width, but the  "site content" area expands and contracts depending on your browsers width.

Here are two pictures visualizing what I am trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKBme.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lg0E.png

When the browser is expanded the side bar is still maintains its original width, but the "site content" has nearly doubled to fill up the space.

The only way I have been able to get site content to expand is to also have the sidebar expand  for example:

```
<style>
#sidebar{
width:20%;
float:right;
}
#sitecontent{
width:80%;
float:left;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
#sidebar{
    width: 256px; /* Use a fixed width for your sidebar. */
    float: right;
}
#sitecontent{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial I use as a foundation whenever I go to build out responsive websites.  (This covers building a site to expand as well as contract all the way to mobile devices)

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#sidebar {
  float: left; width: 200px; /* or whatever */
}
#sitecontent {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; // also -webkit-box-sizing, -moz-box-sizing, maybe -o-box-sizing
  padding-left: 200px; /* same as sidebar */
}
```

By using "border-box" box sizing — which won't work in IE less than 8 — you can set the width of the content box to 100% and have that *include* the padding (and/or border).